# How to make Oracle Apex plugin : "Pretius Nested Reports" to work also with Interactive Grid component?

Tags: nested, report, oracle-apex

**What :**

1. I would like to implement Oracle Apex plugin : **Pretius Nested Reports** on **Interactive Grid** component.
2. **Pretius Nested Reports** Oracle Apex Plugin currently supports only **Classic Report** & **Interactive Report**.
3. How this can be established ?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1 - Install the Plugin**

- Download **Pretius Nested Reports** from : [Here](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:5685756205225::::P710_PLG_ID:apex.nested.reports)
- Easiest way I found to install **Pretius Nested Reports** is by following this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKouL.jpg).
- This installation is based on **Dept / Emp** tables.

---

**STEP 2 - Modify Link Settings for DEPTNO**

1. Go To : Region -> Dept -> Change Type from Interactive Report to Interactive Grid.
2. Go To : Region -> Dept -> DEPTNO ( column ) -> Change type to : **Link**
3. Scroll Down to LINK section and set the following :
4. Target : **URL**
5. Link Text : `<span class="fa fa-search">&DEPTNO.</span><span class="DEPTNO" style="display: none">&DEPTNO.</span>`
6. Link Attributes: `class="dept"`

   It should work now as in image - **if NOT** - you may use example app export file below - just import it to Oracle Apex[image]

- TIP : if loading emp table data ( child table ) takes time, please make sure that in Dynamic action -> advanced - > Event Scope is set to : Dynamic and Static Container (jQuery Selector) is set to : 'body' ( as text without comma )
  **Download Pretius Nested Reports (App) with Interactive Grid Example Based On Dept From** [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ul9xungwq0aulvslo3bl3/f154.sql?rlkey=pd3cgs6590kjqs2kriotzx87s&dl=1)

Another maybe ( didn't check ) alternative is : https://github.com/Pretius/apex-nested-reports/issues/35 , yet, to my humble opinion, the above method is an easier approche.